# Why is this matrix symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis

There is an example in Boyd's convex optimization lecture notes. He just said in the lecture that the matrix which is underlined in red color is symmetric! How can we claim that when there is no assumption on the $V$?

---

[image]

Comment: In general $ABA$ is not symmetric (easy to show in the 2-dimensional case). Are there any other restrictions on $X$ or $V$ you haven't mentioned?

Comment: Does $S^n$ denote the space of symmetric $n \times n$ matrices or the $n$-sphere?

Comment: In any case, even if $X$ is symmetric it does not hold that $XAX$ is symmetric for an arbitrary $A$

Comment: Dear @AndrewWhelan, there is no restriction on $V$. In fact, I just think like you, but it is stated that the matrix which is underlined in red color is symmetric. And I am just confused in this case.

Comment: I voted up @user1551's answer, but in fact it's relatively simple: $f$ is explicitly declared as a function *on symmetric matrices*. You can't even try feeding it an asymmetric matrix, because it's not defined on such. Thus the statement $f:\mathbf{S}^n\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ is precisely what allows you to assume that $V$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the last line:

> *(for any choice of $X\succ0,V$)*

So, somewhere in the lecture notes the author must have assumed that $X$ is positive definite and $V$ is symmetric. Now, when $X$ is positive definite, the usual convention is that $X^{1/2}$ denotes not an arbitrary square root of $X$ but *the unique positive definite square root* of $X$. Hence $X^{-1/2}$ and in turn $X^{-1/2}VX^{-1/2}$ are symmetric.

Comment: Thanks. But, there is no assumption on $V$, which is symmetric or not, because there should not be any restriction on the direction $V$.

Comment: @aminj Well, the lecture notes say that $\operatorname{dom} f=S_{++}^n$, so the $X+tV$ inside $\log\det(X+tV)$ is assumed to be PSD. Since $X$ is also assumed to be PSD ($X\succ0$), there is no way that $V$ can be asymmetric.

Comment: Dear @user1551, based on your nice comments, $V$ is symmetric!